# React and Material UI Div boxes

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to build a mock website using React and Material UI, I used the RaisdedButtonExampleSimple component for buttons from Material UI. This is in a div called App-Intro which is above, the Div "Customer-Choice" with text. The text is appearing above the buttons even though it is in a Div below the buttons in my App.js code. Is there a reason why this is so?

[Picture of the display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5fR8.png)

```css
.App {
    text-align: center;
}

.iconmenu {
    margin: auto;
}

.App-logo {
    /* animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear; */
    height: 200px;
}

.App-header {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 150px;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
}

.App-title {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.App-intro {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.Customer-Choice {}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import "./button.css";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import AppBarExampleIcon from './Navbar';
import {lightGreen600} from 'material-ui/styles/colors';
import BadgeExampleSimple from "./badge";
import IconMenuExampleSimple from "./iconmenu.js";
import RefreshIndicatorExampleLoading from "./refreshindicator.js"
import RaisedButtonExampleSimple from "./button.js"


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
      <div className="App">
    <AppBarExampleIcon iconClassNameLeft={BadgeExampleSimple}
color1 = {lightGreen600} />
{/* <div className = "iconmenu"> <IconMenuExampleSimple/> </div> */}


  
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <div className="button1"><RaisedButtonExampleSimple/></div>
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <h1 className="App-intro">
          Lawn Service and Home Cleaning Done Right
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div className="Customer-Choice">
      
      <h1>Why Customers Choose Us</h1>
      </div>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Do you have any more CSS to show?

Comment: Any working example of this in a JS Fiddle or only partial code?

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the `<h1>Why Customers Choose Us</h1>`, it likely has inherited CSS which is causing the issue.

You can also add a class name to this `<h1 className="customerChoice">` and target it in your CSS as

`.customerChoice { display: block; height: 80px; text-align:center; }`.